# How can I install Chromium browser in Live mode?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, chromium, livedvd

When I attempt to install `chromium-browser`, Ubuntu tells me that it does not exist:

[image]

The [Ubuntu Apps directory](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/chromium-browser/) doesn't list 16.04, and when I click the download button, it results in the error **Package 'chromium-browser' is virtual.**

I'm in a live environment, because I want to debug an issue with one of my Chrome extensions.

I know this has been asked before, but either my situation is different or the previous solutions simply don't work anymore.

Comment: `sudo apt install chromium-browser` doesn't help?

Comment: @Anwar No, that results in what my screenshot is showing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`chromium-browser` resides in the `universe` repository](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/chromium-browser), which is not enabled in the live environment.

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to include the universe repository and retry the installation.

[image]